# Searching for a reference on a congruence relation

Tags: prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients, divisibility

I cannot find a reference for the following fact:
$${n - 1 \choose p - 1} \equiv \begin{cases}
 1 \;\mbox{(mod }p\mbox{ )} & \text{if } \; p \vert n \\
 0 \;\mbox{(mod }p\mbox{ )}  & \text{if } \; p \nmid n. \\
\end{cases}$$
where $n$ is a positive integer and $p$ is a prime number. Could you suggest any book or paper in which such a property is stated and proved?

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Best wishes.

Comment: Note this can be proven relatively easily, such as by using [Lucas's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem).

Comment: The case $1$ I can understand, but does it also apply with the case $0$?

Comment: I noticed that Gould, in a work published in The Fibonacci Quarterly (vol.2 - 1964):

https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/2-4/gould.pdf

has mentioned it in eq. (26) p.249 without pointing any reference.

Comment: For the second case, note that with a denominator of $(p-1)!$, the numerator is the product of the $p-1$ *consecutive* integers from $n-1$ to $n-(p-1)$, inclusive, so one of them is a multiple of $p$.

Comment: Thank you @JonhOmielan. It seems we can solve this second caso also using Lucas' Thm. If $n$ is not a multiple of $p$, then the remainder $r$ must be a number between $1$ and $p-1$. Then, $n - 1$ is $Mp$, a multiple of p, plus $r - 1$, where $0\le r -1 \le p-2$. Thus:
$$
{n-1 \choose p-1} \equiv { Mp \choose 0} {r - 1  \choose p-1} \equiv 1 \times 0 \equiv 0 \; \mbox{(mod }p\mbox{ )}
$$

Comment: You're welcome. Also, what you wrote is correct, with it basically being what I had in mind with my original comment. I'm glad you figured this out yourself.